# Objective-C & Interface Builder for Dummies: How do I bind the keyboard?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios, interface-builder

So, I've been reading through other questions on here and Xcode's documentation, but I'm still a bit confused. Here's the scenario: I have a login screen for my app which has 3 text fields and 1 button. Each text field is bound to have a `Return Key` in IB: Next, Next, Go.

Now, how do I bind these return keys to actual actions where field 1 moves to the next, then field 2 moves to the next, and last field 3 triggers the button?

Some answers for similar questions suggest the use of `textFieldShouldReturn` method, but I'm still fuzzy on it. Somehow I can't see how it auto-magically knows what to do without having some kind of binding...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need to do is use an IBAction to select the next field when the return key is pressed. To do this, first add a method like this to your UIViewController. Make sure to add the method declaration to your header.

```
- (IBAction)selectSecondField:(id)sender
{
    //_secondField is the IBOutlet to the second field
    [_secondField becomeFirstResponder];
}
```

Build and then go to Interface Builder. Select the first text field and open the connections inspector (⌘2) and drag from the dot next to "Did End On Exit" to your controller with the action. A menu of actions will pop up, select selectSecondField.

You will need an action for each field. Alternatively, you could have one action and use sender to see which field was returned.

Comment: Perfect! Exactly the explanation I wanted. I do have a small subquestion, how can I check the sender? I'm not too sure how to treat it...

Comment: Actualy, never mind, I figured out how to check the sender. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

There's a handle (in the connections panel) on each text field called "nextfield" or something along those lines? (I can't remember off the top of my head) But if you drag that to the next box, that's how it knows (manually). I think generally it guesses using the X/Y location, but when you need to manually do it, just drag that handle.

Comment: You are thinking of Mac not iOS.